# How to copy column names if a column equal to something

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to

1. If a column is 1, then copy the column name (to a new column). For example, for ID 1, the Name1 is 1, then we copy 'Name1' (to the 'Name' column). Else, do nothing.
2. If two columns (Name1, Name2) are both 1, then we will have two rows for each name. For example, ID 3.

   ```
   Input

   ID Name1 Name2 
   1   1    0
   2   0    1
   3   1    1

   Output

   ID Name
   1  Name1
   2  Name2
   3  Name1
   3  Name2
   ```

Do I need some advanced keywords to do that?

Comment: do you have more columns or only these two?

Comment: You should read about pivot tables.

Comment: @vkp Actually, it is 3 columns. I assume that is similar to 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function to get the result. This converts your columns into rows, then you can filter the final result based on whether the value of the original column is 0 or 1:

```
select Id, Name
from <yourtable>
unpivot
(
  value for
  name in (Name1, Name2)
) u
where value <> 0
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674860)

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `union all`

```
select id,
    'Name1' as name
from your_table
where name1 = 1

union all

select id,
    'Name2' as name
from your_table
where name2 = 1
```

You could also use `cross apply` if there are more columns:

```
select t.id, x.name
from your_table t
cross apply (
    values (case when t.name1 = 1 then 'Name1' end),
           (case when t.name2 = 1 then 'Name2' end),
           (case when t.name3 = 1 then 'Name3' end)
) x (name)
where x.name is not null;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/DTTV40495)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross apply and get this as below:

```
select Id, nam as [Name] from #yournames
cross apply ( values (name1, 'name1'),(name2, 'name2')) v(n, nam)
where n = 1
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name1 |
|  3 | name2 |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 3 columns, use `union`

```
select id, 'Name1' as Name from Input where Name1=1
union all
select id, 'Name2' as Name from Input where Name2=1
```